# List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

Tags: class, apex

I am getting error

> List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

if I limit the query with one record it's working, but I wanted to get the list of records

```
public static List<Account> AccountsRequiringDebtCase()
    {   
         Integer creditTermDate30 = 2;
         Integer creditTermDate35 = 7;
         Integer creditTermDate45 = 17;
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        if(Date.today().Day()==creditTermDate30){
            accList.add([
                select Id, Has_Open_Debt_Case__c, Most_Recent_Statement_Date__c 
                from Account where
                Has_Open_Debt_Case__c = FALSE and
                Day_60_Balance__c > 0 and Credit_Terms__c = 30 Limit 10

            ]);  
        }
```

List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

Answer (score 0):

You should check document of [Salesforec List Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm)

List.add() support only one element, that's why it error when query return more than one record. You have to use addAll to add list of record

```
accList.addAll(fromList)
```